# How do you pass data from a Fragment to an Activity's onOptionsItemSelected()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

My goal is to have data that is in a Fragment be available to the hosting Activity's `onOptionsItemSelected()` so I can use the data in `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

My goal is similar to a `DialogFragment`'s `getArguments()` method.

Currently, my Activity hosts a Toolbar and a Fragment with a navGraph that switches Fragments. I implement a `NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener` to show and hide the Toolbar actions as needed. For one of the Toolbar actions, the data held in the visible Fragment is needed in the Activity's `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

Currently, I have a few variables in the Activity to hold data across Fragments, and one for the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method. I know this is bad practice, so how do I go about it?

Comment: share some of your code.

Comment: How would that make things more clear? There is a lot of code.

Comment: in that case, I am not good enough to help you. I am sure someone will understand your problem and help you out. Thanks.

Comment: `the data held in the visible Fragment` from where do you get this data in fragment?